# Using JPA native query with zero or more parameters

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

**Goal:** I am trying to build query via JPA which returns a list of locations, nearest to the coordinates passed to the query. The ability to apply filter(s), sort and paginate on the query are required. The following native SQL query is what I came come up with so far:

```
SELECT s.*
   ,sqrt(power(abs(:latitude-g.latitude),2)+power(abs(:longitude-g.longitude),2)) as d 
FROM geolocations g 
   INNER JOIN salons s 
       ON g.zip=s.zip 
WHERE LOWER(s.salon_name) LIKE LOWER(CONCAT('%',:q,'%')) 
ORDER BY d asc limit 

:pageSize offset :offset
```

Paganation, some sorting, and location based search are all working, but I cannot get filtering to work.

The filter requirement states that a user must also be able to filter search results(0 or more filters) by fields, like `owner`,`state`,`zip`... I want to use something like querydsl or the JPA Specification object to build a small query language but I cannot build out a working implementation given the fact that I am using a native query. I am looking for any recommendations on how I could implement the field filters into my existing repository.

Here is my entire repository:

```
public interface SalonRepository extends JpaRepository<Salon,String>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<Salon>{
    @Query("select s from Salon s where s.city = :city and s.state = :state")
    Page<Salon> findByCity(@Param("state")String state,@Param("city")String city,Pageable pageable);

    @Query("select s from Salon s where s.salonName = :name")
    Page<Salon> findByName(@Param("name")String name,Pageable pageable);

    //THIS IS THE ONE I WANT TO ADD THE USER DEFINED FILTERS TO
    @Query(value = "select s.*,sqrt(power(abs(:latitude-g.latitude),2)+power(abs(:longitude-g.longitude),2)) as d from geolocations g inner join salons s on g.zip=s.zip where LOWER(s.salon_name) like LOWER(CONCAT('%',:q,'%')) order by d asc limit :pageSize offset :offset", nativeQuery = true)
    List<Salon> findNearest(@Param("latitude")float latitude,@Param("longitude")float longitude,@Param("q")String query,@Param("pageSize")int pageSize,@Param("offset") int offset);

    @Query(value = "select sqrt(power(abs(:latitude-g.latitude),2)+power(abs(:longitude-g.longitude),2)) as d from geolocations g inner join salons s on g.zip=s.zip where LOWER(s.salon_name) like LOWER(CONCAT('%',:q,'%')) order by d asc", nativeQuery = true)
    List<Float> findNearestInt(@Param("latitude")float latitude,@Param("longitude")float longitude,@Param("q")String query);

    @Query("select s from Salon s where lower(s.salonName) like LOWER(CONCAT('%',:salonName,'%'))")
    Page<Salon> findAll(@Param("salonName")String salonName,Pageable pageable);

}
```

After hours of searching, I am fairly certain I am on the wrong track given the lack of information I've uncovered.

Any and all help is appreciated!

Comment: What is your concrete problem? You can create Strings by just concatenating them like `SELECT location FROM Location location WHERE location." + filter + "=:filter"`.

Comment: Let's say the user has 3 options for filters, `zip`  `state` `city`. If the user only wants to filter by `zip` but not `city` and not `state` the undesired parameters would be left blank. I am not sure how to handle that since I can't query with an empty parameter. I updated the title to hopefully better reflect my issue.

Comment: Well you can either have a permutation of all possibilities or a dynamic query for all. The more dynamic you want, then I suggest you to look into the Criteria API.

Comment: Permutation of all is a possibility but not super desirable due to its excessive verbosity given the amount of parameters I must filter with. I wanted to use the criteria api but since my query must be native due to the query time distance calculation, I understand it will most likely be impossible. What do you mean by "dynamic query for all"?

Comment: queries are nothing but parsed strings, so just create a string and add the parts you require if the user selected a specific option. Something like: `if (zipSelected) { query += "location.zip := zip"; }`

Comment: I see, are you saying I just pass the query into the jpa annotation like such:
`@Query(value = ":query", nativeQuery = true)
    List<Salon> findNearest(@Param("query") String query);`

Comment: That looks like a prime recipe for SQL injection.  You want to build and craft the query yourself, and not let any other outside source build it for you.  I'm thinking that Criteria API would be a decent option for you; is there any mandate that it *must* be a native query?

Comment: FWIW `@Query` is NOT A JPA ANNOTATION. It is a Spring Data JPA annotation, nothing to do with the _standardised_ JPA API

Comment: @thatsIch variable concatenation in annotations? Good joke.

Comment: @Antoniossss why would you try that. Read the rest of the comments.